# Standard deviation about a value other than the mean

Tags: statistics

We generally define standard deviation to be the deviation of the data points about the mean of the whole set, but why about mean? Couldn't we do it about the RMS value? Or any other value?
So I was doing some calculation, on the basis of which it seems to me that the standard deviation is a minimum about the mean.
Definition of standard deviation is ( about $x_0$)

\begin{align*}
\langle（x-x_0)^2\rangle  
&= \langle x^2 - 2 x\,x_0+ x_0 ^2 \rangle \\ 
&= \langle x^2 \rangle - \langle x \rangle ^2 + [ \langle x\rangle ^2 - 2 \langle x \rangle x_0+ x_0^2] \\
&=(\Delta x)^2  + [ \langle x \rangle - x_0 ]^2 .
\end{align*}
So deviation is minimum about the average value!
Is this the reason we always calculate average values in statistical mechanics ?

Comment: Would [statistics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: If it weren't about the mean, it wouldn't be a "deviation". If it were w.r.t to $0$, it would be the 2nd raw _moment_. There really is no other reason to pick another center other than those two.

Comment: Is **what** the reason we always calculate average values?

Comment: JEB 7 ,  we know that standard deviation is about average value, but from the. Definition I can say that if I change x  average  by any other value it would simply mean the deviation about that perticular value.

Comment: @user101134 if you were doing probability distribution functions, you would soon come to realise that taking deviations with respect to the mean makes more sense. Because the density functions peak over the mean (for example in Gaussian, or the Poisson).

Comment: After all, in statistics, people are more interested in standard deviation (how far a number is from the _average value_ in a sample).

Comment: Does density functions always peak over the mean? Then it would simply mean that most probable value of x and average of x are always same.  But I don't think so!   It will only happen if the density function is symmetric about mean.

Comment: It is useful to use parametrised probability distribution functions.  A normal pdf has two parameters, the mean and the standard deviation. If you have a skew distribution or a distribution with multiple maxima you will need more parameters. In such a case the mean and the most likely value need not coincide. Also, the mean may have zero probability. Without specifying the pdf the mean and standard deviation cannot be interpreted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [stats.se]